# inconsistent results for weighted average in numpy masked arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, mask, weighted-average

When I calculate a weighted average in a masked array that is fully masked, I get different results for `weights=None` or `weights=1`:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
a = ma.arange(2.)
a[:] = ma.masked                             # fully masked
ma.average(a)                                # returns NaN, which is ok since all elements are masked
ma.average(a, weights=None,  returned=True)  # returns (NaN, 0.0), which is ok also
ma.average(a, weights=(1,1), returned=True)  # returns 'masked'
```

I would expect the last two lines to yield the same result - i.e. same number of outputs and identical values, but they don't. Most annoyingly, in the last case an error occurs when trying to retrieve the second output argument. Why do I get these results?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this behaviour is annoying, but it's just the way that `numpy.ma.average` is coded. If you look at [its source code](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/browser/trunk/numpy/ma/extras.py?rev=8473), you'll see that around line 505 the if clause executes differently if `weights=None` or if it's something else.

When `weights != None` the operation results in one of the intermediate products being a masked array. Later on in the code (line 562), there is a check for masked arrays in these intermediate arrays, and if true the output will always be masked. The other case when `weights == None` causes a `NaN` to be thrown, so that will be the output.

Don't worry, this inconsistency only seems to happen when all the elements of an array are masked. In real world examples setting weights to `None` or a uniform array will give the same result.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. The conclusion then might be that this is a 2-level bug: 1st, the function crashing when asked for the output it's supposed to return, 2nd the different values returned for (at least semantically) equivalent inputs ...

Comment: @RolfBartstra the fact that it doesn't return a tuple in the last case should be a bug. Just put a `try: except IndexError:` in your function before the call, and should be ok. Or an `if result == ma.masked`.